# Box sizing on inputs in firefox hides text

Tags: css, firefox

I have an issue with Firefox when applying `-moz-box-sizing : border-box;` to inputs, seems like the text I type in is somewhere hidden or overflown or something.

You can see the issue in here : [Test](http://rolandgroza.com/labs/vertica/spf/login.html) ( resize your window to a size smaller than 980px because it's a mobile version );

So what could be the issue there ? Because I tried everything I could find, and the only thing that worked is removing the `-moz-box-sizing : border-box;` property (:

Comment: I've also discovered than on most devices, if you don't have the `16px` on the input, it will zoom in when you focus on it :) I think it was Windows Phone ...

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You should set the height to 100%. I tried the following CSS for your input fields, and it helped:

```
input[type="text"] {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

==> The reason is, that your padding of 20px is too much. Try first removing the padding. You will see that the input field's text gets visible suddenly ;-). After I saw this, I set the height to 100%. Now you can decrease the padding to e.g. 10px and everything looks fine.

Comment: Perhaps the behavior is due to Twitter's bootstrap general styling, it might have the height set to auto or maybe not at all ... but thanks, this seems to take care of the issue (:

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem but initially in Safari 6+. Some text inputs respected padding top/bottom, but others didn't and ended up shorter. By using `height: 100%` on all of them as suggested here, they did all become consistent and seemed to respect padding top/bottom. However, it added a couple extra pixels in height.

In the end, I ended up doing `box-sizing: content-box` on all of them, which made them respect padding top/bottom but without the extra added pixels in height.

Had to chase this with a `width: calc(100% - <padding L+R>)` though, which is a disadvantage.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem differently by adding a custom padding for the input text tags

```
input[type="text"] {
  padding: 6px 12px 12px 6px;
}

input[type="email"] {
  padding: 6px 12px 12px 6px;
}

input[type="password"] {
  padding: 6px 12px 12px 6px;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
input[type="text"] {
padding-top:0;
padding-bottom:0;
vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation?

Comment: This is a bit of a code-dump. It would be nice to try to give a bit of an explanation.