# Text is invisible on bootstrap 3 input text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I got a problem on my form text input using bootstrap 3.0. It works fine in chrome and safari but got problems on firefox and IE.

When I hover on the input box, the usual blue glows on the border but when I click it, I can't see the cursor and can't see the text that I have typed.

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="userEmailAdd">Email</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="useremail" id="userEmailAdd" placeholder="enter your email address" type="email">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="userPassword">Password</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="userpassword" id="userPassword" placeholder="enter your password" type="password">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please chwck your css. use `-moz` for firefox browser

Comment: @Sameer - I think there are no css3 styling on those boostrap classes.

Comment: create a JSfiddle so we can see an example

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
input[type="text"] {
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        font-size: 16px;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 20px;
        width: 100%;
    }    
input[type="email"] {
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        font-size: 16px;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 20px;
        width: 100%;
    }
input[type="password"] {
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        font-size: 16px;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 20px;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

reference: [Box sizing on inputs in firefox hides text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12971300/box-sizing-on-inputs-in-firefox-hides-text)