# Firefox Input Placeholder & Box Sizing

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, placeholder

I can't find too much information on a fix for this but my placeholder text on my inputs are not displaying within FF.

I've seen some fixes out there that refer to the `::-moz-placholder` - tried this and no fix... source: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/p/placeholder/

I have a feeling this could be to do with the **box-sizing** I have enabled on my inputs because when I remove box sizing the placeholders display however, they go manic...

Here is my styling:

```
input {
            height: 26px;
            width: 100%;
            border-radius: 3px;
            -moz-border-radius: 3px;
            color: #333;
            padding: 23px 10px 20px 10px;
            display: block;
            box-sizing: border-box; /* css3 rec */
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* ff2 */
            -ms-box-sizing: border-box; /* ie8 */
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* safari3 */
        }
```

Comment: Seems like removing `height: 26px;` works in firefox.

Comment: I tried that and unfortunately that didn't work - I thought it would have. My firefox just updated to the most recent so that could be a factor for you too?

Comment: Probably that could be a factor also though I have updated my firefox to latest (v31) earlier and seems like removing the `height` works fine :)

Answer (score 1):

The solution for this question is found here: [Box sizing on inputs in firefox hides text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12971300/box-sizing-on-inputs-in-firefox-hides-text)

Set height of input to 100% and reduce padding as per.